# Issue with bilingual topic analyzer

Tags: python

I am developing a topic analyzer for research I am doing where I am handling documents in both English and French. I approached that by handling a dictionary with tokens according to whether they were in French or English. However, my algorithm returns a NoneType value when I run it. Is it a problem with the way the code handles the dictionary? Here's the concerned piece of code:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.decomposition import LatentDirichletAllocation
from langdetect import detect
from scipy import sparse

class Test:
    def __init__(self, lang='bilingual'):
        self.lang = lang
        self.vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.90, min_df=0.10, max_features=1000, ngram_range=(1, 2))
    def analyze(self, processed_sentences):
        print("Processed sentences: {}".format(processed_sentences))
        tfidf_matrix = self.vectorize(processed_sentences)
        if tfidf_matrix.shape[0] > 0:
            print("TF-IDF vectorizer objects created for {} sentences".format(self.lang))
        else:
            print(tfidf_matrix)
        lda_model = self.topic_modeling(tfidf_matrix)
        print(f"\nTopics:")
        self.plot_topics(lda_model.components_, self.vectorizer)

    def plot_topics(self, topics, tfidf_vectorizer, num_top_words=10):
        """
        Plot the top words for each topic using the given topics, tfidf_vectorizer, and num_top_words.

        Parameters:
            topics (array-like): The topics to be plotted.
            tfidf_vectorizer: The TF-IDF vectorizer used to extract feature names.
            num_top_words (int, optional): The number of top words to display for each topic. Defaults to 10.
        """
        try:
            feature_names = tfidf_vectorizer.get_feature_names_out()
            for topic_id, topic in enumerate(topics):
                print(f"Topic {topic_id + 1}:")
                top_word_indices = topic.argsort()[:-num_top_words - 1:-1]
                top_words = [feature_names[index] for index in top_word_indices]
                print(", ".join(top_words))
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error plotting topics: {e}")

    def vectorize(self, documents):
        """
        Vectorizes the given documents using the internal vectorizer and returns the TF-IDF matrix.

        Args:
            documents: A list of documents to be vectorized.

        Returns:
            The TF-IDF matrix representing the vectorized documents.
        """
        try:
            processed_documents = []
            if isinstance(documents, dict):
                # Handle bilingual documents dictionary
                tfidf_matrices = []
                for lang, sentences in documents.items():
                    tfidf_matrix_lang = self.vectorizer.fit_transform(sentences)
                    print(f"TF-IDF matrix created for {lang}!")
                    tfidf_matrices.append(tfidf_matrix_lang)
                # Concatenate the TF-IDF matrices for each language
                tfidf_matrix = sparse.vstack(tfidf_matrices)
            elif isinstance(documents, list):
                # Handle single documents
                for doc in documents:
                    lang = detect(doc)
                    processed_documents.append((doc, lang))
                tfidf_matrix = self.vectorizer.fit_transform([doc for doc, _ in processed_documents])
                print("TF-IDF matrix created!")
            return tfidf_matrix
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error while vectorizing documents: {e}")

    def topic_modeling(self, tfidf_matrix, num_topics=5):
        """
        Perform topic modeling on the given TF-IDF matrix using Latent Dirichlet Allocation (LDA) algorithm.

        Parameters:
            tfidf_matrix: The TF-IDF matrix representing the input document-term matrix.
            num_topics: The number of topics to be generated (default is 5).

        Returns:
            lda_model: The trained LDA model for topic modeling.
        """
        try:
            lda_model = LatentDirichletAllocation(n_components=num_topics, max_iter=100, learning_method='batch', random_state=42)
            lda_model.fit(tfidf_matrix)
            print("LDA model built!")
            return lda_model
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error while initializing LDA model: {e}")

# Input example
example = {
    'fr': ['soir e', '4', 'novembre', '2019', 's.e.n.c', '.', 'marie-clair', 'pinet', 's.o', '.', '17', '495', 'infiniment', 'monsieur', 'gauthier', '.'],
    'en': ['sam', '2007', 'richard', 'florida', 'sorry', 'jacobin', 'magazine', 'august', '27', '2017']
}
test = Test()
test.analyze(example)
```

Here's the traceback error that the code returns:

```
Processed sentences: {'fr': ['soir e', '4', 'novembre', '2019', 's.e.n.c', '.', 'marie-clair', 'pinet', 's.o', '.', '17', '495', 'infiniment', 'monsieur', 'gauthier', '.'], 'en': ['sam', '2007', 'richard', 'florida', 'sorry', 'jacobin', 'magazine', 'august', '27', '2017']}
Error while vectorizing documents: After pruning, no terms remain. Try a lower min_df or a higher max_df.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\nicol\Documents\UdeM\Maîtrise\Données\scorpion_data\topic_analysis\test_playground.py", line 97, in <module>
    test.analyze(example)
  File "c:\Users\nicol\Documents\UdeM\Maîtrise\Données\scorpion_data\topic_analysis\test_playground.py", line 13, in analyze
    if tfidf_matrix.shape[0] > 0:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Note that changes in `min_df` and `max_df` do not affect the result.

Comment: Please show which line of code produces the error.

Comment: I edited the thread by adding the error traceback for my issue.

Comment: The error message is telling you that `tfidf_matrix` is `None`, which means that your `vectorize` function is not returning a valid reference.